# BOM caused by _GPL_e6a00_parent_div?

Tags: php, byte-order-mark

When I reload my php page, in the top left corner it's displaying: **ï»¿**

I've been searching for it and I got the `BOM` issue.

But I've another issue:
In the exactly same position, inspecting the element, it has something that seems some kind of hack. There is an object and one div, with `_GPL_swf` and `_GPL_e6a00_parent_div` as it's id's respectively.

I'm in doubt if the BOM comes from this two elements** or from my own stuff.

What do you think? Any clue how to remove it?

Comment: If this is your project, how come you don't know why those elements are in your source? Either *you* put them there, in which case they're OK, or you didn't, in which case they're not a good sign...

Comment: @DCoder if it was me putting it there I would know if for sure :)
By searching with the _GPL_e6a00_parent_div? key (https://www.google.pt/search?q=_GPL_e6a00_parent_div&oq=_GPL_e6a00_parent_div&aqs=chrome.0.69i57j69i59j69i65j69i62l3.1725j0&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) you see that probably it's something bigger than my stupidity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The BOM is there because you saved your file as UTF-8 with signature most likely on windows, try saving as UTF-8 without signature in your text editor. Also verify that you've added the following to the `head` tag:

```
<meta charset="utf-8"/>
```

Comment: the meta was like your suggestion, thank you. 

About the UTF-8 without signature, I'm trying to work on it (I'm using Jedit for Windows 8. I knew I should had stay in Fedora...)

Thanks!

Comment: Solved with Notpad++! The _GPL_e6a00_parent_div is still there, anyway. It just needs to have the <html> tag to appear even if there is nothing in the body. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I found the same HTML tag on a customer's computer which was inserted right at the beginning of the `<body>` tag:

```
<div id="_GPL_e6a00_parent_div" style="position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px; width: 1px; height: 1px; z-index: 2147483647;"><object data="http://cdncache-a.akamaihd.net/items/e6a00/storage.swf?r=1" id="_GPL_e6a00_swf" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" height="1" width="1"><param value="transparent" name="wmode"><param value="always" name="allowscriptaccess"><param value="logfn=_GPL.items.e6a00.log&amp;onload=_GPL.items.e6a00.onload&amp;onerror=_GPL.items.e6a00.onerror&amp;LSOName=gpl" name="flashvars"></object></div>
```

Since most computers did not have this, and since it was not there in another browser on the same computer, I thought it had to be related to some plugins, and it turns out that by disabling them, the tag was no longer inserted there.

I am still trying to figure out which plugin caused this, since there were so many installed, but disabling Shockwave Flash plugin from Firefox solved the problem for this computer.

Answer (score 0):

The following is caused by loading the CSS with the `media` attribute set to `screen`:

```
<link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" />
```

When using Inspect Element in FF, I saw the following:

```
<div id="_GPL_e6a00_parent_div" style="position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px; width: 1px; height: 1px; z-index: 2147483647;"
<object id="_GPL_e6a00_swf" width="1" height="1" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="http://cdncache-a.akamaihd.net/items/e6a00/storage.swf?r=1"></object>
```

Removing the `media` attribute resolved the issue.